# Is there Amazon API for Amazon Stores?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-advertising-api

I would like to know if there's an existing API for Stores on Amazon.com? A way for developers to get the Insights from the Stores.

Service: https://advertising.amazon.com/en/solutions/products/stores

I wanna develop a integration with the service

Answer (score 0):

From [Amazon Ads API - Manage campaigns programmatically | Amazon Ads](https://advertising.amazon.com/about-api):

> The **Amazon Ads API** provides a way to automate, scale, and optimize advertising. Campaign and performance data for Sponsored Products, Sponsored Brands, and Sponsored Display are available through the API, enabling programmatic access for campaign management and reporting. Amazon Attribution (beta) insights are also available through the Amazon Ads API. Amazon Attribution can help measure the full-funnel impact non-Amazon Ads media such as search ads, social ads, display ads, video ads, and email marketing. **Insights** throughout the shopping journey including clicks, detail page views, and purchases can be utilized to optimize campaign ROI.

Answer (score 0):

There is a new Amazon Brand Stores insights API that was just released:

- [Release note](https://advertising.amazon.com/API/docs/en-us/info/release-notes#access-valuable-brand-stores-insights-from-the-amazon-ads-api)
- [API reference](https://advertising.amazon.com/API/docs/en-us/stores/open-api#/Stores%20Analytics)